# Convert Julian Date to Timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, epoch, julian-date

I have a table full of "Julian Dates", that is the number of days and seconds away from **1/1/2035**. I need to convert these to normal postgres timestamps. Can anyone help?

```
--Converts '2000-06-20 12:30:15' into an Epoch time base which gives a result of -12612.478993055556
select (EXTRACT(epoch FROM ('2000-06-20 12:30:15'::timestamp - '2035-01-01 00:00:00'))/86400.00) as run_ts

--Question, how to convert -12612.478993055556 back into '2000-06-20 12:30:15'
select -12612.478993055556 ??? as run_ts
```

Comment: If `-12612.478993055556` truly is an "epoch" it needs to result in `1969-12-31 21:29:47.521`  as an "epoch" is the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Yes agreed, I should have clarified it isn't true epoch, hence my pain :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) to convert an epoch to a timestamp.

The epoch you posted does not correspond to 2000-06-20, as you have removed another date 2035-01-01 from it.

```
select (EXTRACT(epoch FROM ('2000-06-20 12:30:15'::timestamp )));
 date_part
-----------
 961504215
(1 row)

select to_timestamp(961504215);
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2000-06-20 08:30:15-04
(1 row)


select to_timestamp(-12612.478993055556);
         to_timestamp
-------------------------------
 1969-12-31 15:29:47.521007-05
(1 row)
```

**EDIT**

Since you are not considering a true epoch but really a difference between two dates, you can simply add this difference to the reference date. You can use the `day` interval to remove the need to multiply by 86400 (seconds/day)

```
select  '2035-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1' day *  -12612.478993055556;
      ?column?
---------------------
 2000-06-20 12:30:15
```

Comment: Yes I should have clarified, the date in question is very important. The data platform which houses this information decided 2035-01-01 was the date to measure from and true, so it is not true Epoch time, hence my issues. I am currently playing with your solution to try and account for this after using to_timestamp :)

Comment: Thanks @JGH this was just what I needed, I essentially tried that but failed. Nice one!